# User web control handle OnClientClick event

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have next user web control:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Myfunction() {
        alert('Hello');
    }
</script>
    <asp:Panel Id="problemSolving_panel"    runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Hello world" OnClientClick="javascript:Myfunction();return false;"/>
    <fieldset class="fieldsetsElement">
        <legend class="legendsElement">
            <input Id="callToAbonent"   runat="server" type="checkbox" onchange ="ChangeEnable(this.checked, 'callToAbonentDiv');"/>
            <label for="callToAbonent">Call to abonent:</label>
        </legend>
        <div Id="callToAbonentDiv">
            <asp:CheckBox   Id="isCallToAbonentFailed"          runat="server" Text="Call to abonent failed"   Enabled="false"/>
            <br />
            <asp:Table runat="server" Enabled="false">
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox    Id="datesOfCallTrying"              runat="server"                             />
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Hello world" OnClientClick="javascript:Myfunction();return true;"/>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
            </asp:Table>
            <br />
            <asp:Button     Id="addInfoAboutCall_button"  runat="server" Text="Add info about call" Enabled="false" OnClick="OnAddInfoAboutCall"/>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</asp:Panel>
```

When I click to Button1, OnClientClick handle this event, display me 'Hello' without any postback to server, but when I click to Button2 (copy-paste of Button1), OnClientClick not handle click event and server server get postback. I can not understand why it happend, because I donn't need postback. Can anybody tell me what's wrong in my code?

Comment: Use return false in the javascript end. This will cancel the postback

Answer (score 2):

You are not getting postback from button1 because you are return `false` from `OnClientClick` from `button1` and you get postback from `button2` because you return `true` from `button2`.

- If you return true from javascript handler you will get postback.
- If you return false from javascript handler you will **Not** get
  postback.

The button1 return `false`

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Hello world" 
 OnClientClick="javascript:Myfunction();return false;"/>
```

The button2 return `true`

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Hello world" 
OnClientClick="javascript:Myfunction();return true;"/>
```

You can return true or false from the event handler function

```
function Myfunction()                   
{
    //Your code
    if(SomeCondition)
       return true;
    else
       return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have problem because onclick event is empty for button in table: <table class="aspNetDisabled">
  <tr>
   <td><input name="ctl00$MainContent$ProblemDisplay1$datesOfCallTrying" type="text" disabled="disabled" id="MainContent_ProblemDisplay1_datesOfCallTrying" /></td><td><input type="button" name="ctl00$MainContent$ProblemDisplay1$Button2" value="Hello world - test" disabled="disabled" id="MainContent_ProblemDisplay1_Button2" /></td>
  </tr>
 </table>

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps amend your onclientlcick and function

OnClientClick="javascript:return Myfunction();"

```html
function Myfunction() {
        alert('Hello');
        return false;
    }
```